# How to add front end validation in bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have integrated the `bootstrap-wysihtml5` editor to description section in my rails application. Now I want to add the client side validation so that it would validate the presence of description field. I used [bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails) gem.

The editor is being initialized with following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#description').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).wysihtml5({
            toolbar: {
                "fa": true, // use Font Awesome
                "font-styles": false, // Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc.
                "emphasis": true, // Italics, bold, etc.
                "lists": false, // (Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers.
                "html": false, // Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML.
                "link": true, // Button to insert a link.
                "image": true, // Button to insert an image.
                "color": false, // Button to change color of font
                "blockquote": false // Blockquote
            }
        });
    });

})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to just use max and min count..you can use the default maxlenght and  minlenght provided by html...

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't worked for me.

Comment: You can give a try to jquery.validate js and set up validations on any field that you want....refer http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by adding the events as suggested by the [documentation](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)

```
$('#some-textarea').wysihtml5({
    "events": {
        "load": function() { 
            console.log("Loaded!");
        },
        "blur": function() { 
            console.log("Blured");
        }
    }
});
```